# how to display my list with n amount on each line in Python

Tags: python

im trying to display my list with 7 states on each line here is what i have so far, but it displays as one long string of all the states with quotes around each state. I forgot to mention that this is for my CS class and we havent learned iter yet so we not allowed to use it. the only hint i was given was to to turn STATE_LIST into a string then use '\n' to break it up

```
state = str(STATE_LIST)

displaystates = Text(Point(WINDOW_WIDTH/2, WINDOW_HEIGHT/2), state.split('\n'))
displaystates.draw(win)
```

and STATE_LIST looks like this

```
STATE_VOTES = {
"AL" : 9, # Alabama
"AK" : 3, # Alaska
"AZ" : 11, # Arizona
"AR" : 6, # Arkansas
"CA" : 55, # California
"CO" : 9, # Colorado
"CT" : 7, # Connecticut
"DE" : 3, # Delaware
"DC" : 3, # Washington DC
"FL" : 29, # Florida
"GA" : 16, # Georgia
"HI" : 4, # Hawaii
"ID" : 4, # Idaho
"IL" : 20, # Illinois
"IN" : 11, # Indiana
"IA" : 6, # Iowa
"KS" : 6, # Kansas
"KY" : 8, # Kentucky
"LA" : 8, # Louisiana
"ME" : 4, # Maine
"MD" : 10, # Maryland
"MA" : 11, # Massachusetts
"MI" : 16, # Michigan
"MN" : 10, # Minnesota
"MS" : 6, # Mississippi
"MO" : 10, # Missouri
"MT" : 3, # Montana
"NE" : 5, # Nebraska
"NV" : 6, # Nevada
"NH" : 4, # New Hampshire
"NJ" : 14, # New Jersey
"NM" : 5, # New Mexico
"NY" : 29, # New York
"NC" : 15, # North Carolina
"ND" : 3, # North Dakota
"OH" : 18, # Ohio
"OK" : 7, # Oklahoma
"OR" : 7, # Oregon
"PA" : 20, # Pennsylvania
"RI" : 4, # Rhode Island
"SC" : 9, # South Carolina
"SD" : 3, # South Dakota
"TN" : 11, # Tennessee
"TX" : 38, # Texas
"UT" : 6, # Utah
"VT" : 3, # Vermont
"VA" : 13, # Virginia
"WA" : 12, # Washington
"WV" : 5, # West Virginia
"WI" : 10, # Wisconsin
"WY" : 3 # Wyoming
}

STATE_LIST = sorted(list(STATE_VOTES.keys()))
```

I am trying to get it to look somewhat like this
[image: Sample]

Comment: It looks like your using a library to render the text. We need to know what that is to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
STATE_LIST = sorted(STATE_VOTES)

def my_iter(iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        yield item

from itertools import izip_longest

s = ',\n'.join(', '.join(state for state in group if state) for
                        group in izip_longest(*[my_iter(STATE_LIST)]*7))

print s
```

Output:

```
AK, AL, AR, AZ, CA, CO, CT,
DC, DE, FL, GA, HI, IA, ID,
IL, IN, KS, KY, LA, MA, MD,
ME, MI, MN, MO, MS, MT, NC,
ND, NE, NH, NJ, NM, NV, NY,
OH, OK, OR, PA, RI, SC, SD,
TN, TX, UT, VA, VT, WA, WI,
WV, WY
```

The example uses `izip_longest()` from the `itertools` module. If you're not allow to use that standard library for some reason, there's equivalent source code for it is right in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=izip_longest#itertools.izip_longest).

Comment: `I forgot to mention that this is for my CS class and we havent learned iter yet so we not allowed to use it.`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: OK, I replaced the use of `iter()` with something equivalent (known as a generator function). As you should be able to see, there's not much to it to be learned...

Answer (score 0):

With this line:

```
state = str(STATE_LIST)
```

you are just turning the list into a string, accepting whatever format Python chooses to use. In this case, the string representation will just be

```
["AL", "AK", ..., "WY"]
```

with no newlines in it at all. Just one long string that looks like the list.

The string that you really want appears to be this one:

```
AL AK AR AZ CO CT DC DE FL
GA HI ...
              ... WI WV WY
```

(You seem to have put 9 or 10 items on each line; not sure how that's going to work in five lines, with 51 items to list, but let's make it flexible)

Suppose you want to split it into five lines. You could do that with something like this:

```
# Start with an empty list
state_lines = []

# Calculate the maximum number of items in each row
items_per_row = (len(STATE_LIST)+4)/5 # If you wanted, you could just say "11" here.

 # First item will be 0, 11, 22, etc.
 for first_item in range(0, len(STATE_LIST), items_per_row):

    # This contains all of the states for this line. For example,
    # ["AL", "AK", "AR", "AZ", "CO", "CT", "DC", "DE", FL", "GA", "HI"]
    states = STATE_LIST[first_item : first_item + items_per_row]

    # state_line will be a string of states separated by spaces,
    # like "AL AK AR AZ CO CT DC DE FL GA HI"
    state_line = ' '.join(states)

    # Add the new state line to the list
    state_lines.append(state_line)

# Finally, join the lines together with newlines in between them
state = '\n'.join(state_lines)
```

Then your `state` variable will have the string that you need for the rest of your code.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is for my CS class and we havent learned iter yet so we not allowed to use it. the only hint i was given was to to turn STATE_LIST into a string then use '\n' to break it up

Comment: That's pretty important to know :) Whether the question is raised in the context of learning the basics of the language, or just "how can/should I do this in Python" obviously has a pretty big effect on the answer. I'll break that line up into more easily-understood pieces

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something simple like this:

```
>>> counter = 1
>>> for i in STATE_LIST:
...    sys.stdout.write(i+' ')
...    if not counter % 7:
...        print '\n'
...    counter += 1
... 
AK AL AR AZ CA CO CT 

DC DE FL GA HI IA ID 

IL IN KS KY LA MA MD 

ME MI MN MO MS MT NC 

ND NE NH NJ NM NV NY 

OH OK OR PA RI SC SD 

TN TX UT VA VT WA WI 

WV WY
```